# Problems Passing a jpg BLOB from an Access 365 Query to a VBA function

Tags: vba, ms-access, user-defined-functions

I have BLOB jpegs in an ESRI SDE/MS SQL table which I am linked to in an MS Access database.  I think I have written a VBA function (below) that will (I think) offload them to my Temp directory.  Using a variant of this code which includes an embedded DAO SQL query (not shared here), I can successfully offload a photo.

Rather than writing 3 different functions to account for points, lines, and polygons, I want to invoke the function in an Access query, passing it two different integer values and the BLOB field contents.

In building the Access query, I pass the three arguments to the function, but it never actually calls the function.  Within this same query, I successfully call a different function passing data that data.  I am baffled as to why this function call in my Access query:

```
PicFileLoc: Blob2File([Landfill_InspectionPoint_Attach_vw].[ATTACHMENTID],[Landfill_InspectionPoint_Attach_vw].[DATA],[Landfill_InspectionPoint_evw].[ItemNo])
```

does not call this function.  What obvious thing am I missing?  Can BLOBs not be passed to user defined functions?  If I change the data type for blbData from Byte to String, the code begins to run, but it obviously will fail as the BLOB is not a string.

```
Public Function Blob2File(ByVal intAttID As Integer, ByVal blbData As Byte, ByVal intItemNo As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo Blob2FileError
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim nFileNum As Integer
    Dim abytData As Byte
    abytData = blbData
    Blob2File = Null

    strFile = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Local Settings\Temp\" & intItemNo & "_Pic_" & intAttID & ".jpg" 'placed in the users temp directory on the local c drive.
    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Binary Access Write As nFileNum
    Put #nFileNum, , abytData
    Blob2File = strFile

Blob2FileExit:
    If nFileNum > 0 Then Close nFileNum
    Exit Function

Blob2FileError:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
           "Error writing file in Blob2File"
    Blob2File = Null
    Resume Blob2FileExit

End Function
```

Thanks,

Dale

Comment: As Erik wrote, a query is not a good way to do this. Use a **Recordset** loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to close the loop, I have gotten the function to work as I desired.  To be clear, since the code can be called when least expected, using the RecordSet is desired method, but since I am time constrained and this works, I am using it as is and I will share it below.

While I was fighting with VBA and trying to understand what was supposed to go on, I had changed the Byte array to a string and then conveniently forgotten that.  So once Erik provided the Byte Array piece of information, I should have been all set, but I had forgotten that I had made the change to what I was passing.

I am using a cell phone to take jpeg pictures of field conditions at landfills that need to be repaired.  In ESRI's ArcGIS Collector, it stores the photos in a related table where they are trapped in ESRI's ecosystem.  I am using this function as one of the steps in generating an Access report showing photos and descriptions.

This is the function call from the Access query:

```
PicFileLoc: Blob2File([ATTACHMENTID],[DATA],[ItemNo])
```

and this is the function:

```
Public Function Blob2File(ByVal intAttID As Integer, ByRef blbData() As Byte, ByVal intItemNo As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo Blob2FileError
    'This function is based off of this link: http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/read_write_blob.html
    'and modified for my needs.  Dale R. Bridgford 2019-09-06
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Local Settings\Temp\" & intItemNo & "_Pic_" & intAttID & ".jpg" 'placed in the users temp directory on the local c drive.
    Dim nFileNum As Integer
    Dim abytData() As Byte
    Blob2File = ""
    nFileNum = FreeFile
    abytData = blbData
    Open strFile For Binary Access Write As nFileNum
    Put #nFileNum, , abytData

    Blob2File = strFile 'passes back the path and filename of photo.

Blob2FileExit:
    If nFileNum > 0 Then Close nFileNum
    Exit Function

Blob2FileError:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
           "Error writing file in Blob2File"
    Blob2File = ""
    Resume Blob2FileExit

End Function
```

Thanks to all who helped me.

Dale

Answer (score 1):

You're allowing your blob data to only be a single byte, while it's a byte array.

Change it to a byte array by adding () to the name in the declaration, and the type in the function call:

```
Public Function Blob2File(ByVal intAttID As Integer, ByVal blbData As Byte(), ByVal intItemNo As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo Blob2FileError
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim nFileNum As Integer
    Dim abytData() As Byte
    abytData = blbData
    Blob2File = Null

    strFile = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Local Settings\Temp\" & intItemNo & "_Pic_" & intAttID & ".jpg" 'placed in the users temp directory on the local c drive.
    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Binary Access Write As nFileNum
    Put #nFileNum, , abytData
    Blob2File = strFile

Blob2FileExit:
    If nFileNum > 0 Then Close nFileNum
    Exit Function

Blob2FileError:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
           "Error writing file in Blob2File"
    Blob2File = Null
    Resume Blob2FileExit

End Function
```

Note that I strongly recommend against writing files inside a query. The database engine might call the function multiple times based on a variety of conditions, or not at all if it decides only to display part of the records until all are displayed.

Comment: Thank you Erik and Andre for your assistance.  You were correct with the revision that changing the function declaration to:

````
ByVal blbData() as Byte
````
helped it along.  The code runs and writes a file that is not a jpg.  However, every other example of this function that I have seen brings blbData in as an Object.  When I make that change, the function is never called.

Comment: I presume that an Object is a basic element to VBA that shouldn't require adding any references.
BTW, this is going to be a recurring issue with many different tables, which is why I passed on Recordsets and chose this route.  My tables have different fields.

Comment: Also, the jpg that it writes is twice the size as is reported in the SQL table.

Comment: Bringing in a BLOB as an object is plain wrong if it's a bytearray. Start with narrowing down the issue: is the data passed to the function identical to the JPEG data? And is the data being written to the file identical to the data being passed to the function? The last condition can be checked by reading back the data after writing it, the first can be checked by directly looking at the SQL server table or creating a test record with easily identifiable data.

Comment: So, I am not sure if it really is a byte array.  I have been trying to adapt the FileToBlob code from here: [link](http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/read_write_blob.html) which is where I had was trying to bring it in as an Object.  In the SQL table, it is a varbinary(MAX) field.  It is a jpg file and I can get the photo out when I go through the whole recordset process, but I was trying to avoid creating a VBA function for each and every table where there are photos. Rather, I was hoping to create a function that could be called from whatever query (for a report) I need at the time. Thx.

Comment: ... If you don't know what the type of something is, just determine it. Pass it as a variant, and call `TypeName(SomeVar)`

Comment: Thank you very much, Erik.  I had foolishly changed something in my query which was hosing what I was sending to the function.  Now that I have gotten out of my own way, it works as I wanted.  Thank you again and have a good weekend.

Comment: If your out file is not a .jpg you should go a step back and check how you "read" the Blob in the 1st place.